# Creating new column with values based on old columns including NA

Tags: r, case, na, mutate

I have a dataset where I'm focusing on 2 specific columns. I want to create a new column with the following:

[image]

How can I do this in R?

Thanks

This is the code that I tried, which didn't work. Gave me an error. Also, I wasn't sure how to include all the NA values in this code.

```
data_2=data_1%>%mutate(majoramp_indX=case_when(c("amplevel_r","amplevel_l")>=2~1,c("amplevel_r","amplevel_l")<2~0))
```

Then I also tried this, which gave me all 1s in the new column

```
data_1$majoramp_indX=case_when(c("amplevel_r","amplevel_l")>=2~1,c("amplevel_r","amplevel_l")<2~0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO Mufti!

There is a point that needs clarifying in your two conditions: what to do if, for example A = 1 and B = 2? Is the result 0 or 1? To get you going, I've done code for the two conditions.

To code your first condition, you can then do

```
library(dplyr)
myData <- myData |> mutate(Con1 = ifelse((A %in% c(2:5) | (B %in% c(2:5))), 1, NA))
```

For your second condition, you can do

```
myData <- myData |> mutate(Con2 = ifelse((A %in% c(1, NA) | (B %in% c(1,NA))), 0, NA))
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Using `myData <- structure(list(A = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), B = c(1, 
+                                                                    2, 3, 4, NA, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
+                                                                                                                                         11L))`

Comment: I get `myData <- structure(list(A = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), B = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, NA, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1), Con1 = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), Con2 = c(0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row. Names = c(NA, 
11L))`